# Cannot read property 'onchange' of undefined error when calling function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have popular error about Angular 2. When I'm calling function from another component I face this error.

`"Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined at CD019.onChangeParent"`

My codes below:

```
  @ViewChild('testComponent') testComponent: CD020;

onChangeParent() {
    this.testComponent.onChange;

}
```

and child component is

```
   @Output() childChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
    onChange(value: string, test: string) {
        this.childChanged.emit(value);
        this.Test(test);
    }
```

Thanks for your help already.

Comment: What error(s) do you get? Can you post them in your question? Also, if you are calling a function on your child, you must add parentheses at the end of a function call. `this.testComponent.onChange() //added ()`

Comment: The error is "Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined at CD019.onChangeParent". I tried with () and parameters but it doesn't change.

Comment: Can you also post your html for the parent? And what type is your child component? Is it `CD020`?

Comment: Yes, its type is CD020. I posted it, i'm using child component with selector in parent html. but i want to trigger child's function when i'm using parent's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you shall use the component type as the identifier for the ViewChild decorator.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html

```
@ViewChild(CD020) testComponent: CD020;
```

Comment: @canberkdogmus if the answer solved your issue. You should mark it as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `@ViewChild(ChildType) testComponent: ChildType` uses the same type E.g.your child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-child',
  templateUrl: './my-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-child.component.css']
})
export class CD020 implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    @Output() childChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
    onChange(value: string, test: string) {
        this.childChanged.emit(value);
    }
}
```

your parent html:

```
<app-my-child></app-my-child> <!-- uses the template selector name -->
```

your parent code:

```
//note the name inside the viewChild and the type of testComponent
@ViewChild(CD020) testComponent: CD020;

onChangeParent() {
    // must pass two arguments.
    this.testComponent.onChange("someValue","someTest");

}
```

Comment: If ViewChild is used the way you suggest (with the selector name), wouldn't the field testComponent be an ElementRef or a TemplateRef?

Comment: @Hampus, I am sorry, I was writing the wrong answer. You should use the type of the component inside the `@ViewChild()` as well.